# NodeJS Selecionar base de dados ao logar

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sequelize-js

Olá, boa tarde.

Estou mexendo com um projeto que funcionará como serviço, o cliente tem um pouco de conhecimento em TI e solicitou que os usuários pudessem selecionar a base de dados ao logar, por exemplo:

Na tela de de login além do usuário e da senha, haveria um dropdown com a lista de empresas, quando eu fosse logar eu escolheria a empresa X e tudo que eu fizesse seria armazenado na base de dados da empresa X. Quando o usuário da empresa Y logasse seria da mesma forma de modo que a mesma aplicação se conectasse a N bancos de dados.

o motivo disso é que além da prestação de serviço ele dará backups diários aos clientes e também dará acesso ao banco.

Minha dúvida é: É possível  fazer isso com NodeJS? isso é viável do ponto de vista de desempenho? (levando em consideração que seria uma única instancia da aplicação rodando)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível de várias formas!
Mas vamos abstrair qual banco e falar sobre arquitetura.

Eu crio uma base de dados com as informações de conexões de cada EMPRESA.
Pode incluir qual DB vai usar, senhas, connectionstrings..

Se eu pensar em BACKEND abstraindo o front, precisamos pensar que cada request para API vc deveria ter todas as informações necessárias para saber qual BASE vc deve fazer as consultas.

Então ao fazer um LOGIN na plataforma, eu iria criar um JWT com algum identificador de qual base o usuário está consultando, uma idéia mais prática.

Exemplo de um JWT (https://jwt.io/)

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJRRzIiLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzg0NDc1NTcsImV4cCI6MTYwOTk4MzU1NywiYXVkIjoicWcyLmNvbS5iciIsInN1YiI6ImFydGh1ckBxZzIuY29tLmJyIiwidXVpZCI6IjM4OTk0ZTg2LWNhMTktNGYyMi04MTM0LTIxN2MxYTUzZjM5MCJ9.bJWf_Rk0eG2Kp-TVxENCI-QQLr2CDQzvTnsVEKaes2A
```

Se vc colar esse JWT no site informado acima tem o seguinte resultado

```
{
 "iss": "QG2",
 "iat": 1578447557,
 "exp": 1609983557,
 "aud": "qg2.com.br",
 "sub": "arthur@qg2.com.br",
 "uuid": "38994e86-ca19-4f22-8134-217c1a53f390"
}
```

O uuid seria o identificador na minha base aonde eu sei que é a EMPRESA X e lá eu tenho informação para me conectar na base de dados, e faço a consulta necessário ou INSERT enfim.

Você pode criar uma classe em NodeJS que recebe o UUID e lá ela resolve isso pra vc ;)

Espero ter ajudo

abs!

Comment: Muito obrigado, Arthur. Estava com dificuldade até mesmo para pesquisar, não sabia muito bem nem como fazer a busca, sua resposta ajudou a abrir meus horizontes rsrs. É uma solução aparentemente simples de implementar e resolve bem o problema. Mais uma vez muito obrigado!